# user_generated results in a story with no title or action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I post stories with these parameters (1)

```
{
'meal':(meal url),
'fb:explicitly_shared':'true',
'image[0][url]':(image url)
}
```

The story shows up fine with this text in the activity log: "(User) ate (Meal name)" and a small image

Once I add the user_generated parameter (2)

```
{
'meal':(meal url),
'fb:explicitly_shared':'true',
'image[0][url]':(image url),
'image[0][user_generated]':'true
}
```

The story shows up with a big picture, but no action text! All that is seen is "(User)" as a link, and the image next to it. No action name, no object name. What gives?

See attached screenshot:
[image: screenshot of activity log]

Posting Code (PHP SDK)

```
                $params = array(
                    'meal'=>$url,
                    'access_token'=>$token,
                    'fb:explicitly_shared'=>'true',
                    'image[0][url]'=>$imageUrl,
                    'image[0][user_generated]'=>'true',
                    'timestamp'=>date('c',strtotime($model->visible_date)-1),
                );
                if(!empty($meal->description)) {
                    $params['message']='I had '.$meal->description.' '.$url;
                }
                $out = $facebook->api('/me/appname_:have','POST',$params);
```

Comment: Does this url which you send 'meal' have Meta tags for description

Comment: yes it does, that's how it works without the user_generated parameters.